# dynamic input box to update insert and delete in my sql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple form but I want to dynamically change the form action from insert to update    in same page and I want to show the values in the same page. I have written update in `href` link. Please help me.

```
<?php
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="test";

  include"db.inc.php";
  $order = "SELECT * FROM tablename1";
  $result = mysql_query($order);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo ("<tr><td>$row[sno]</td>");
   echo ("<td>$row[name]</td>");
   echo "<td ><a href=\"test.php?id=".$row['sno'] . "\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to edit datas?');\">Edit</a></td>";
   echo "<td><a href=\"insert1.php?id=".$row['sno'] . "\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');\">Delete</a></td></tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are [deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). Use  [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Here is good [PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Thanks bro . i am new to stack over flow and php

Comment: Rather than dynamically changing the form action I would normally send the form to a single php script which can then work out whether it needs to create a new record or update an existing one.

Comment: I would agree with @Al_. You should look at using a common php script and pass a parameter through to it (possibly using a hidden field within the form) depending upon the action you wish to complete whether it be insert or update.

Comment: What is your test that determines if it should be an update or insert? And I agree with @peterm, you need to use prepared statements. Much cleaner and less vulnerable to injection attacks

Answer (score 0):

i thought you are  asking dynamic insert/update/delete in single page.

if it is a case u should use ajax call.after get the response from server, change your form as insert/update/delete dynamically through javascript

if u want to learn ajax start with this

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.ASP

i guess it might helpful to u.........